# Getting 403 error in non-public API but not blocked from domain

Tags: c#, rest, web-scraping, cloudflare

I hope everything is good with you!

I created a tool in C# that would run every day and was able to fetch me the prices of all the products in certain categories of my choice from the Cex website ([uk.webuy.com](https://uk.webuy.com/)). I used this tool to keep a price history for the products but one day, as the tool was executing, it started getting a 403 error. I haven't been able to diagnose why this is happening since other end-points from this domain work completely fine.

Here is the code I have been using for the last 6 months for the request:

```
public static List<Box> GetCategoryProducts(List<int> largeCategoriesList)
        {
            List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>();

            foreach (int categoryId in largeCategoriesList)
            {
                int currentCategoryProducts = 0;
                int firstRecord = 1;
                int count = 50;
                int totalRecords = 0;
                int minDelay = 3;
                int maxDelay = 6;
                int retryDelay = 10; // Retry after 10 seconds if response isn't successful

                bool hadError = false;
                int retryCount = 0;

                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string weBuyAPILink = $"https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/boxes?firstRecord={firstRecord}&count=50&sortBy=relevance&sortOrder=desc&categoryIds=[{categoryId}]";
                        var client = new RestClient(weBuyAPILink);
                        client.Timeout = -1;
                        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headerList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Refer", "https://uk.webuy.com"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Origin", "https://uk.webuy.com"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br")
                        };

                        request.AddHeaders(headerList);
                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                        if (!response.IsSuccessful)
                        {
                            Logger.Error($"Request response encountered an error! Error details: {response.StatusCode}");
                            hadError = true;
                            Thread.Sleep(retryDelay * 1000); // Retry after 10 seconds
                            retryCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //PROCESS RESPONSE
                            //.......
                            //.......
                            hadError = false;

                            var random = new Random();
                            var delay = random.Next(minDelay * 1000, maxDelay * 1000);
                            Logger.Info($"Waiting {delay / 1000} seconds before next request...");
                            Thread.Sleep(delay);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Fatal(ex, "Fatal error processing category list!");
                        // Handle fatal error as needed
                        hadError = true;
                    }
                } while ((currentCategoryProducts < totalRecords || totalRecords == 0) && !hadError && retryCount < 3); // Retry only 3 times

                if (hadError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to get price info");
                }
            }

            return boxes;
        }
```

Trying to access the URL on a browser will give a Cloudflare page saying that I have been blocked and that I can no longer access webuy.io, but, for example, accessing the [product detail](https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/boxes/sps4500gb001/detail)
endpoint that gives me only the details from a specific product, works fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've been looking at Cloudflare bypasses but I haven't invested a lot of time in them because I think that won't solve my issue.

I looked into this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Dionakra/webuy-api) when building my tool as it had some insightful information about the API.

I tried changing some request headers, tried using a VPN, and also tried using ScraperAPI and ScrapeOps to fetch me the information without getting the 403 error but to no avail.

Comment: You need some techniques like TLS, and JA3 ( maybe JA4 in the future ) fingerprinting, where your requests mimic the real browsers. Unfortunately, in C#, you can not modify the TLS handshake part (at least on Windows). You can use interop libs written in other languages (GO has many libraries that allow browser mimicry) or you can use headless browsers to achieve what you want even headless browsers can be detected they also have some plugins to mimic the real browsers.

Comment: @Eldar I'll try to create a script with your method in some other language just to see if I can get it to work and I'll let you know, but I'm not too confident that anything can be done since other end-points are working without any issues. Cheers.

Comment: Any success so far? It just seems like the API endpoint has been shut down

Comment: @Steven unfortunately no success. I asked this question to see if anyone could show me how to better diagnose this issue as I'm currently not very experienced with this sort of issues.
The fact that it would throw a 403 Forbidden and then tell I was blocked from accessing the domain was confusing me in the end, but thinking about it, it more than likely was just shut down.